# How to apply a function to one element in a heterogeneous list?

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to work out the most haskell-ish way to do the following (as still a reasonable beginner):

You have a heterogeneous list with different types inside. In my code I'm using `Show`. What I want to achieve is to do something to one element in this list as well after showing it. Currently you would write (naively)

```
[show a, show b, (++) " " $ show c, show d, show e]
```

Is there some way to pack the function `(++) " "` with the value `c` so you could write something like

```
map show [a, b, inverseShow ((++) " ") c, d, e] -- not real haskell
```

or is this not possible in the language?

I am aware you can use existential quantifiers to get part way there

```
data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s
instance Show ShowBox where show (SB s) = show s

map show [SB a, SB b, SB c, SB d, SB e]
```

but I'm struggling to see how to move from this to my desired functionality in the 'best practice' way?

EDIT: After reading the comments below, I've pretty much come to the conclusion this is not the best way to write the code. Below is an implementation of the sort of behaviour I wanted:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShowAndTell = forall s. Show s => STell s (String -> String)
instance Show ShowAndTell where show (STell s f) = f $ (show s)

st :: (Show a) => a -> ShowAndTell
st a = STell a id

addSpace :: String -> String
addSpace x = x ++ " "

main = (mapM_ putStrLn) . (map show) $ [st "1", st 3, STell 5.5 addSpace]
```

This outputs `"1"`,`3`,`5.5` but could be described as rather ugly!

Comment: What does you want the `inverseShow` to do ?

Comment: You can't have an heterogeneous list of different types. So I'm not sure what the hypothesis is here.

Comment: @Sibi You have `a` and a function `String -> String`. You want to turn this function into something which still implements `Show` but has the effect of applying that function afterwards. I guess you could type `inverseShow` like `inverseShow :: (String -> String) -> a -> InverseShow f a` where `show InverseShow f a = f . show a`. Probably inverseShow is not the best name for this!

Comment: As far as I understand, your problem is: you have 5 elements of different types (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) and want to keep them in a list? Well, as Jeffrey pointed out, it isn't possible in Haskell, because all the elements of a list must have the same type. _However_, you could use a tuple for it. Or you could use a data type for it. Storing them as `String`s in a list isn't the idiomatic Haskell way, if that is your question.

Comment: It is usually a "best practice" to look for an ordinary value level solution to a problem before using type level or quantified constraint level programming, like building actual [heterogenous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-HList-HList.html) or using existential qualification (which is completely pointless for `Show`). What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: I've edited the question with a 'solution' to the problem I was trying to solve, though looking back it does feel like an overcomplication. Particularly since my main problem was just trying to write cleaner code than writing `show` 5 times...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have 5 items, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` and the only thing you know about them is that they have `Show` instances, you can put everything<sup>†</sup>  you know about them in a list by `show`ing them before you put them in the list.

```
items :: [String]
items = [show a, show b, show c, show d, show e]
```

If you want to do different things to the different elements of the list, like add a space before the third one, you can make a list of the different things to do.

```
changes :: [String -> String]
changes = [id, id, (++) " ", id, id]
```

Then apply the `changes` to the `items` in the list by zipping the two lists together, applying (with `$`) the change to the corresponding item.

```
changed :: [String]
changed = zipWith ($) changes items
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Techically `Show` has two other methods than `show` which would be captured by existential quantification, [`showsPrec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec) and [`showList :: [a] -> ShowS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:showList). An existentially qualified `showList` is completely useless, the only thing you can do with it is repeat the same element over and over again (`showList []`, `showList [x]`, `showList[x,x]`, etc) because you can't prove that any other items have the same type to be put in a list with it. If you need `showsPrec` you don't need `show` because `show = ($ "") . showsPrec 0`.

Comment: `zipwith ($)` is really nice. This is also much more normal logic than my approach. Nice answer!